# method().bind(this) + Angular4 getting Cannot read property 'myFun' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, google-picker

I'm integrating Google picker API in my application. I'm following the official documentation [Google Picker API](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/)

I have successfully done my job, but after adding below code I am unable to use class methods and variables. Getting Cannot read property of undefined error

```
gapi.load('auth', {'callback': this.onAuthApiLoad.bind(a)});
```

Complete code is:

```
onApiLoad() {
    var a= this;
    gapi.load('auth', {'callback': this.onAuthApiLoad.bind(a)});
    gapi.load('picker');
  }

  onAuthApiLoad() {
    gapi.auth.authorize(
        {
          'client_id': this.clientId,
          'scope': this.scope,
          'immediate': false
        },
        this.handleAuthResult);
  }

  handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
      if (authResult.access_token) {
        var pickerBuilder = new google.picker.PickerBuilder();
        var picker = pickerBuilder.
            enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN).
            setOAuthToken(authResult.access_token).
            addView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS).
            setCallback(this.myFun).
            build();
        picker.setVisible(true);
      }
    }
  }

  myFun(e){

}
```

Comment: `this.handleAuthResult.bind(this)`?

Comment: Thank you geek, I am new to javascript and confused about this bind(), can you share stuff regarding this?

Comment: Where are you getting the error? Put a breakpoint on the first line of `onAuthApiLoad`. What is the value of `this` at that breakpoint?

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1009922).

Answer (score 0):

I have added below line to handle auth request

```
this.handleAuthResult.bind(this)
```